# Send a form to twig template

Tags: entities, 8, theming

How I can pass a form to twig template in Drupal 8?

For example, I get this:

a form: mymodule/src/Form/MyForm.php

Then on my Controller:

```
public function myController() {

    ??????

    return [
        '#theme' => 'mytemplate',
        ??????
        ];
}
```

mytemplate.html.twig

```
{{ ????? }}
```

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the entity object available in the preprocess/template, or you'd like the rendered view of the entity available?

Comment: @Clive I want the rendered view of the entity available for send to template and then this show it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "render entity". nodes and blocks have a similar API to get displayed, but forms are quite different and definitely aren't an entity. Ask a specific question and you will get an answer that will help you. what kind of entity, do you just want to view with the default output, or use it in your own template, ...

Comment: Let me then edit the question.

Comment: That's still not enough information. So again, what kind of entity do you want to output? And what is your template doing exactly. In short, what is your input and expected output. Also include your hook_theme() implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I did it, for anyone that needs this:

```
public function pageAction() {
  $myform = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\[mymodule]\Form\[myformclass]');
  // If you want modify the form:
  $myform['field']['#value'] = 'From my controller';

  $build = [
    '#theme' => 'mytemplate'
    '#form' => $myform,
  ];
}
```

In twig:

```
{{ form }}
```