# This form was missing from the server cache on Drupal 8

Tags: forms, caching, 8

On my site I do this:

I got a form with this field:

```
'myfile' => [
  '#title' => $this->t('MyTitle'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://myfolder',
],
```

And MyController:

```
$myform = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\[mymodule]\Form\[myclassform]');
```

This variable I pass to Twig template.

On my template:

```
{{ myform }}
```

Every is ok.

But when the page is cached I got this error when i upload a file:

```
An unrecoverable error occurred. Use of this form has expired. Try reloading the page and submitting again.
```

I dont use memcache or CacheRoute, only drupal cache for anonymous user.

How I fix that?
Is possible not cached the form?

Comment: Where are you embedding that form? I guess in something that is being cached, like an entity or a block?

Comment: @Berdir I embed the form on a custom page, I do it like [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/send-a-form-to-twig-template-in-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that prevent that drupal cached the page, this way, because the forms can't be cached:

```
// Deny any page caching on the current request.    
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

**EDIT:**

Recently was commited [Add #cache[max-age] to disable caching and bubble the max-age](https://www.drupal.org/node/2443073)

When `$build['#cache']['max-age']` is not set, permanent cacheability `(Cache::PERMANENT)` is assumed.

To indicate that a render array is not cacheable at all, set `$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0` (i.e. zero seconds).

And to indicate that a render array is cacheable only for a limited amount of time, e.g. 5 minutes, set `$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 300; // 5 * 60 = 300`.