# How to render a form in custom template?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm looking to add a form inside a custom template. The form, if I open the path registered inside the file cmodule.routing.yml, works but if i try to use it inside a custom template it doesn't work: with a dump(form) or dump(form.anyfield) i get NULL.

cmodule.routing.yml:

```
cmodule.manageform:
  path: '/cmodule/manageform'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Documents'
    _form: '\Drupal\cmodule\Forms\RequestForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
cmodule.manage:
  path: '/cmodule/manage'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\cmodule\Controller\CmoduleController::manageAction'
    _title: 'Custom Documents'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

RequestForm.php:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['type'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#options' => array(
            '0' =>t('DOC'),
            '1' =>t('PDF')
        ),
    );
    $form['pid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('ID:'),
        '#required' => FALSE
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        '#attributes'=> ['class'=>['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-search']],
    );


    return $form;
}
```

cmodule.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function cmodule_theme(){

    $templates = array(
        'manage_cmodule_page' => array(
            'variables' =>
                [
                    'id' => NULL,
                    'form' => NULL
                ],
            'template' =>'manage_cmodule',
            'render element' => 'form'
        )
    );

    return $templates;
}
```

the controller contains:

```
public function manageAction() {

        $id = 1;

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\cmodule\Forms\RequestForm');

        $form['type']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';

        return [ '#theme' => 'manage_cmodule_page',
            '#form' => $form,
            '#id' => $id,
        ];
    }
```

and then the template/view (contains):

```
<div>
 {{ form.form_token }}
{{ form.form_build_id }}
{{ form.form_id }} 
{{form.type}}
{{form.submit}}
</div>
etc..
```

But as I said above the template doesn't show the form, but show (if i print it) the #id value passed through the controller. 
Do you have any suggestions?!

---

**UPDATE #1**
I tried also to follow the suggestion of Beebee, and then [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263382/86468) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/send-a-form-to-twig-template) so the code is:

controller:

```
controller contains:

public function manageAction() {

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\cmodule\Forms\RequestForm');

        $render['#form'] = $form;
        $render['theme'] = 'manage_cmodule_page';
        return $render;;
    }
```

and the implementation of hook_theme in .module file is:

```
return [
    'manage_cmodule_page' => [
        'template' =>'manage_cmodule',
        'render element' => 'form',
    ]
];
```

The result is an empty page with an error inside the apache log:

> [php7:error] [pid 12660:tid 1592] [client ::1:59521] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Out of memory (allocated 270532608) (tried to allocate 266354688
>   bytes) in
>   C:\drupal\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Debug.php on
>   line 60, referer: http://localhost/drupal/

if I remove the following row from the controller

```
$render['theme'] = 'manage_atps_page';
```

the page loads, but it is empty (without any form).

**UPDATE #2**

I fixed my issue following also the idea of [Alex Kuzava](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/264114/86468). Thus I used the code of UPDATE 1, with the new directory of the form, and then I added these 3 lines inside the  part of my template (otherwise the submit button doesn't work).

```
{{ form.form.form_build_id }} 
{{ form.form.form_id }}
{{ form.form.form_token }}
```

Comment: `id` is one of those things that'll always be set in a variable array. It's not a good indicator of whether something is working or not.

Comment: hi, I put here id var only to show you that others variables work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a form to twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/send-a-form-to-twig-template)

Comment: This question gets asked a lot lately. Also see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263382/15055

Comment: @leymannx i already saw both links; in one of them i also put a question (i cannot create comment yet), but it has been removed with the suggestion to create a new question.

Comment: That is relevant info and you should add that into your question. Also add what exactly didn't work in the mentioned answer.

Comment: Have you also seen the second answer I mentioned? Have you tried the `$form['#theme'] = 'manage_cmodule_page';` approach?

Comment: @leymannx yes i did. I just updated the question with some extra informations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 'render element' => 'form'

Your render element is **form** which means all provided variables will be passed there.

In your twig template you can render your form like here

```
<div>{{ form.form }}</div>
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

Wow man, you have wrong namespace **Drupal\cmodule\Forms\RequestForm**

Should be **Drupal\cmodule\Form\RequestForm**

Please rename Forms to Form (the same for directory) and clear cache. It should help you.

Comment: it doesn't work. please read the update #1

Comment: @quele I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: @quele any news?

Comment: I fixed it changing the Form directory, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x

> Each information array must contain either a 'variables' element (for using a #theme element) or a 'render element' element (for render elements), **but not both**.

Your `manage_cmodule_page` expects both `variables` and `render element` which is not allowed. Removing `variables` array from your hook_theme should make this work, provided the rest of the code is functional.

Comment: I updated my question, because it still doesn't work.