# How can I access individual form elements for theming?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have overridden the default user login form in Drupal 8 using a different template in my sub theme, but it isn't of much use because when I access it in twig template, all I can do is

```
<form {{attributes}}>
{{children}}
</form>
```

Doing this I get the elements in same order, and there is not lot of modification option. I can put them in container but that is it. I was wondering there was instead a way to call elements like username field, password field individually instead of doing a bulk call using `{{children}}`.

Comment: [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263967/how-to-render-a-form-in-custom-template) might help

Comment: The template you've overridden now is a theme wrapper. For accessing form elements inside of the form see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249856/custom-registration-twig-template

Answer (score 1):

That's a case for the new [Formdazzle!](https://www.drupal.org/project/formdazzle) module.

> #### Drupal form theming with less pain
>
> Theming drupal forms can be difficult and time-consuming. This module
>   provides a set of utilities that make form theming easier.
>
> Currently, this module provides theme suggestions for forms that are
>   much more useful than those provided by Drupal core.
>
> - Theme suggestions for all form elements (including buttons)
> - Theme suggestions for all form element labels
> - All theme suggestions include the form ID and the form element name; e.g. `[element-type]--[form-id]--[form-element-name].html.twig`
>
> While Drupal core only provided these two theme suggestions:
>
> ```
> input.html.twig
> input--textfield.html.twig
> ```
>
> Formdazzle adds the following two theme suggestions to the list:
>
> ```
> input--textfield--webform-contact-form.html.twig
> input--textfield--webform-contact-form--first-name.html.twig
> ```